# Ruby Executing Fiddler Script

Tags: ruby, automation, rubygems, fiddler, request-headers

I am try to add request headers for all urls in my selenium automation and I am using ruby.

Is there any way to execute fiddler script using ruby as we can execute javascript using `driver.execute_script()`?